# Google Sheet Query Fomula - How to filter with weeknumber

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I want to filter with the week number in Col3 but the below function is producing an empty array.

`=QUERY(Form Responses!A:T,"Select Col9,Col8,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col7,Col19,Col20, Col5, Col6, Col18 Where Col1 = 'On-time' AND Col3 ='"&WEEKNUM(TODAY())&"'",1)`

Comment: What's in Col3?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(Form Responses!A:T,
 "select Col9,Col8,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col7,Col19,Col20,Col5,Col6,Col18 
  where Col1 = 'On-time' 
    and Col3 ="&WEEKNUM(TODAY()), 1)
```